# How to I integrate Regex with php/sql script?

Tags: php, regex

again Experts,

I am grateful to have gotten the help of Jason Sperske with the regex below:

```
$pattern = "/(\d{2})([ND]?)(\d*)(GG[\d]*)?/";

function format($matches) {
  return $matches[1][0].(strlen($matches[2][0])>0?$matches[2][0]:" ").$matches[3][0].(strlen($matches[4][0])>0?"  ".$matches[4][0]:"");
}
```

The regex helps format values entered for an ID field.

For instance, if a user enters `12343GG90494`, the regex will insert 2 spaces before the **GG** thereby producing the following output `12343  GG90494`.

This is just one example of how the regex formats user input.

This is important because users of our apps often don't put the 2 extra spaces and a result, their searches produce no results.

The regex above solves that problem for us.

My issue right now is to use the regex with the following sample query:

```
$tid = $_GET["tid"];

// Connect to SQL Server database
include("../connections/TDConnect.php");

 $tsql = "SELECT * FROM TC(dtops.dbo.tSearch, Name, '\"$tid*\"')";
```

How do I use it with the input param called $tid?

Your assistance, as always, is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to the TDConnect.php its hard to know exactly what you need so this advice is generic (well i guess MySql specific but not that much so). Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)! Specifically for this problem:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col LIKE (?)"))) {
  echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $tid)) {
  echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for coming to the rescue. I can see that I didn't make myself very clear. First, I am using SQL Server db. Second, I have the query that I need already. I just want to know how to integrate
 your regex with this: 

$tid = $_GET["tid"];

such that when I pass a variation of those IDs we worked on, we can get the correct format.

Example, is this what I would need?

$tid = $_GET["tid"];

format($tid)???. The format being the function you wrote?

Comment: You can use this '$tid = format($_GET["tid"]);' to go from query string parameter to PHP formatted variable. As for the SqlServer part, sorry I missed that. I hope this helps, good luck getting your code to work.